Power BI Report Server (PBIRS) authentication and SSO
I have set up a PBIRS and need to delegate authentication.
For this I plan to use Keycloak which supports, among other things, SAML and Kerberos.
I read that PBIRS also supports these protocols.
My question is: is it possible to put Keycloak as an authentication brick in front of PBIRS.
Thank you in advance for your answers.
I haven't tested anything yet, I'm thinking about the architecture of my system.
